# What is the maximum index value of a list collection?

Tags: apex, list

What is the maximum index value of a list collection? For example, the below code,

```
String str = 'a.b.c.d.e.f';
List<String> lst = str.split('\\.');
```

lst[0]
lst[1]
lst[2]
lst[3]
....
lst[n]

What could be the maximum value for "n" the index value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists must be accessed by an Integer, which has a maximum value of 2^31-1, or 2,147,483,647. This is the hard limit for lists.

However, other limits will cause you to have a much smaller soft limit. For example, around 3,000,000 elements (assuming an Integer-sized value), you'll run into heap limits in synchronous code, or many less elements if the objects are larger. The larger limits for asynchronous code still won't allow you to reach anywhere near the logical list size before exhausting the heap.

Also, the 10,000 ms CPU limit for synchronous code will limit your maximum usable list size to a much smaller limit, probably less than 1,000,000 elements for simple use cases, and much smaller if you want to do anything meaningful with that list, such as sorting values.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any explicit limit for the list size.

However there are a lot of implicit limits which will apply for instance the heap limit of 6MB (or 12 in async contexts) mentioned here:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

So i dont think there is a fixed limit at all for lists

Comment: While it is not documented, there *is* a hard limit, by definition of the language.